# What's the difference between laugh and laughter?

Tags: difference

> Everywhere, they can see beautiful flowers and smiling faces, and hear pleasant and_____.(laugh)

**What's the difference between laugh and laughter?**
I don't know the difference.
Can you tell me? Thanks!

Comment: Have you looked in a dictionary?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A laugh refers to a single vocalisation that people make when they are amused. It may be a brief laugh or slightly extended. If a person continued to laugh beyond a second or two, you might say that s/he **was laughing**.

**Laughter** generally - although not necessarily - refers to vocalised group amusement - when two or more people laugh. We talk about **the sound of laughter**, referring to the the vocal expression of amusement.

There are several types of laugh, described as chuckles, giggles, guffaws, sniggers (and more). You can look them up.

Synonyms for laughter are **mirth** and **merriment**, which are also used mainly to describe amusement among a group of people.

You should note that the difference between **laugh** and **laughter** can easily be determined simply by looking for the definitions online. They can be found in numerous online dictionaries.  You should make this effort before asking questions.

https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/laugh
https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/laugh

Comment: Thank you very much.I will make this effort before asking questions.But I'm a middle school student in China.....And I'm not good at English...

Comment: @YangJingbo Well, you certainly write well enough, which is an excellent start.

Answer (score 0):

You can't *hear pleasant **and** [also hear] **something else***, because ***pleasant*** is an adjective (it must be immediately followed by a noun, not by ***and***).

---

You could *hear pleasant **laughter*** or maybe *hear pleasant **laughing*** (both highlighted elements being "abstract / mass nouns").

OR you could *hear **a** pleasant **laugh*** (a single instance of the act of laughing).

---

The relationship between ***a laugh*** and ***laughter / laughing*** is the same as that between ***a cry / shout / sneeze*** and ***crying / shouting / sneezing*** (a single act, or something happening repeatedly over time). It just so happens that the "gerund" sense of ***laughing*** can also be expressed using the broadly synonymous alternative derived form ***laughter***.